# How to make three way data binding in Angular & Firebase?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm new in angular and firebase so it is not clear for me.
I am now working on an e-commerce application specifically on the shopping cart page.
I have a collection in the database called 'cart' which contains products as documents and i get its data stored in an **array** of objects in my **cart.component.ts** file.
Then I loop this **array** in the **cart.component.html** file to display its data as the cart items.
All of this works perfectly, but what I'm trying to do now is to link the value of '**qty**' with its value in the database, So when the user changes it, it is changed in the database as well.

**here is (cart.component.ts) file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Goods } from 'src/app/interfaces/goods';
import { CartService } from './../../services/cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-cart',
  templateUrl: './shopping-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-cart.component.scss']
})
export class ShoppingCartComponent implements OnInit {

  cartGoods: Array<Goods>;

  constructor(private cartSer: CartService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cartSer.getCartGoods().subscribe(data => {
      this.cartGoods = data.map(el => {
        return {
          id: el.payload.doc.id,
          ...el.payload.doc.data()
        };
      });
    });
  }

}
```

**here is (cart.component.html) file:**

```
<ul class="cart">
  <li *ngFor="let good of cartGoods">
    <img [src]="good.img" [alt]="good.name">
    <h4 class="name"> {{ good.name | titlecase }} </h4>
    <strong class="price"> {{ good.price | currency }} </strong>
    <input class="qty" type="number" [(ngModel)]="good.qty">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Word of caution:

Updating the database to stay in sync with quantity may not be a good idea because -- assuming you mean an HTTP request -- it would mean many more requests than is necessary and slow down your app.  Consider a user pressing the up or down arrow on your number input to change quantity.  Each time a change occurs, an HTTP call would be made.  Is there no option for a Submit or Save button that the user can click to indicate that she is done setting quantity?

#### To do what you asked:

The simplest way to do this is probably to bind to the `ngModelChange` output of the `ngModel` directive:

```
<input class="qty" type="number" [(ngModel)]="good.qty" 
        (ngModelChange)="saveQty(good)">
```

This way you will execute `saveQty` and pass it the product whenever the model value changes.  From there you can save `good.qty` wherever you want.

#### Additional Advice

What I've offered will work but it is not easily scalable or testable.  I suggest for your greatest long term benefit that you learn how to use the ReactiveForms API to control every form behavior in your component class. For this specific use case, I would use `FormArray` to dynamically create as many inputs as is needed for the items in the cart.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you are using ReativeForms you can also add an `debounceTime` to your `valueChnage` detector in order to avoid to many backend calls.